dockerized spring boot error while instantiating MqttClient
Im trying to instantiate MqttClient in my MqttClientService like this
    public MqttClientService(KipitProperties properties) {

        String connectionString = String.format("%s://%s:%s",
                properties.getMqtt().getProtocol(),
                properties.getMqtt().getUrl(),
                properties.getMqtt().getPort());

        try {
            this.publisher = new MqttClient(connectionString, properties.getMqtt().getPublisher().getId());
        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getMessage(ex));
            log.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));
        }
    }


The application runs fine on my local machine, however i get this error when i deploy my docker image which i made using jib
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mqttClientService' defined in file [/app/classes/com/kipit/wallet/event/mqtt/MqttClientService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.kipit.wallet.event.mqtt.MqttClientService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not initialize MqttClients
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at com.kipit.WalletServiceApplication.main(WalletServiceApplication.java:40)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.kipit.wallet.event.mqtt.MqttClientService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not initialize MqttClients
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:306)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not initialize MqttClients
    at com.kipit.wallet.event.mqtt.MqttClientService.<init>(MqttClientService.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

I think the problem is that MqttClient cant create the file for file persistence inside of the docker container (base image is openjdk:17-oracle)

are you using any annotation on this method and class ? Also can you pls share the content of your Dockerfile ?

Check the container names in your docker-compose file and make sure they only contain valid characters for hostnames (ASCII(7) letters from a to z, the digits from 0 to 9, and the hyphen (-), but no underscores (_)).
Especially Java follows hostname rules strictly, as discussed in this question.
